# How early are things open on Venice Beach, California, USA?

Tags: air-travel, usa, lax

I have a flight out of LAX around 11AM, but I'm going to be getting into the area around 6AM or so. Will any good breakfast restaurants be open along Venice Beach before 9:30AM or would I be better off just going to LAX and eating/hanging around there?

Comment: What sort of things?

Comment: Anything really. I don't know that area very well and I'd have about 2.5 hours or so to kill. I know some places don't really open until 9:30, so I'm not sure if it would even be worth it to make the extra trip

Comment: Well, "anything" is quite braod and I am afraid they willl mark it as broad. Are you interested in breakfast places for example? cafes?

Comment: Ahh I see what you're saying. Yes, I would be looking for somewhere to go get breakfast along that stretch. I'll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: If a place is open for breakfast, they'll be open from 7 at least. What day of the week? A weekend day versus a work day may have different hours.

Comment: It would be on a Thursday

Comment: Well....  Certainly the Marriott MDR will be open for breakfast at or near 6AM. I have been in there at the crack of dawn sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll find no shortage of Breakfast locations along Venice beach, all open from at least 8am, many 7am or earlier.

Although I've never been there for breakfast, it's hard to go past Figtree's Cafe, if only for the view and because they do a half-price happy-hour from 8am to 9am.

Other than food venues you won't find much else open until around 10am.